# How to create a specific SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `CONTRACTOR_SCHEDULER` table. Letters in columns "Schedule" mean working time (m - 8:00-20:00, n - 20:00-8:00(next day), d - 8:00-8:00(next day), h-day off). (`Name, Begin_date`) is unique.

| Name | Schedule | Begin_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | nhmh | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-08 |
| John | nnh | 2019-01-09 | 2019-01-25 |
| Kate | dh | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-07 |
| Kate | mnhdh | 2019-01-08 | 2019-01-14 |
| Mike | nh | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 |
| Mike | mh | 2019-02-02 | 2019-12-31 |

I need a SQL Server stored procedure that creates new table `CONTRACTOR_WORK_DAY` of working days using `CONTRACTOR_SCHEDULER` rows (days off do not appear in table).

Example:

First row - John has schedule nhm. First letter is n so begin_date - 2019-01-01 20:00, End_date - 2019-01-02 08:00. Next letter is h, skip it as a day off. Last letter is m so begin_date - 2019-01-03 08:00, End_date - 2019-01-03 20:00. Repeat schedule until 2019-01-08 - end_date in first table.

Table for the first row of `CONTRACTOR_SCHEDULER` would be:

| Name | Begin_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2019-01-01 20:00 | 2019-01-02 08:00 |
| John | 2019-01-03 08:00 | 2019-01-03 20:00 |
| John | 2019-01-05 20:00 | 2019-01-06 08:00 |
| John | 2019-01-08 08:00 | 2019-01-08 20:00 |

I wrote this in python using some loop over schedule string etc. but can not figure out how to do it in T-SQL for SQL Server.

Comment: You should replace your "Schedule" column with four bit columns m, n, d, & h.

Comment: @NicholasHunter - What about Kate who has a 5 character schedule?  Or Annoying BobbyTables who might have a 21 character schedule?

Comment: OK, separate table for the shifts, foreign key into the schedule table. Your current design is going to be a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option.

Not sure if I agree with the last record of the desired results.  I have `2019-01-07` while you have `2019-01-08`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=73c4e90aadd33aff084e137ccb09b32a)**

```
Select A.[Name]
      ,[Begin_Date] = convert(datetime,left(dateadd(DAY,N       ,[Begin_date]),10)+' '+BegTime)
      ,[End_Date]   = convert(datetime,left(dateadd(DAY,N+NxtDay,[Begin_date]),10)+' '+EndTime)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( left(replicate(Schedule,10),datediff(DAY,Begin_Date,End_Date)) ) )B(S)
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select N=N-1
                     ,Subs=substring(B.S,N,1)
                 From (  Select Top (len(S)+1) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1 ) B1
             ) C
 Join ( values ('m','08:00','20:00',0)
              ,('n','20:00','08:00',1)
              ,('d','08:00','08:00',1)
      ) D(SchdCd,BegTime,EndTime,NxtDay) on Subs=SchdCd
 Order By [Begin_Date]
```

**Results**

```
Name    Begin_Date                  End_Date
John    2019-01-01 20:00:00.000     2019-01-02 08:00:00.000
John    2019-01-03 08:00:00.000     2019-01-03 20:00:00.000
John    2019-01-05 20:00:00.000     2019-01-06 08:00:00.000
John    2019-01-07 08:00:00.000     2019-01-07 20:00:00.000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH
  numbers AS
(
  -- Generate a table of values (from 0 upwards)
  -- Must be at least as long as the longest schedule string
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sv.number) - 1   AS id
  FROM
    master..spt_values  sv
),
  pivotted AS
(
  -- Create one row for each day in the date range
  -- Extract the relevant character from the schedule for each day
  SELECT
    c.*,
    n.id  AS date_offset,
    SUBSTRING(c.schedule, (n.id % LEN(c.schedule)) + 1, 1)  AS schedule_char
  FROM
    CONTRACTOR_SHERULER   c
  INNER JOIN
    numbers               n
      ON n.id <= DATEDIFF(DAY, c.begin_date, c.end_date)
)
-- Add a number of days to the begin_date
-- Then add a number of hours based on the current character from the schedule
SELECT
  pivotted.*,
  DATEADD(
    HOUR,
    CASE pivotted.schedule_char WHEN 'm' THEN 8
                                WHEN 'n' THEN 20
                                WHEN 'd' THEN 8  END,
    DATEADD(DAY, date_offset, pivotted.begin_date)
  )
    AS begin_datetime,
  DATEADD(
    HOUR,
    CASE pivotted.schedule_char WHEN 'm' THEN 20
                                WHEN 'n' THEN 32
                                WHEN 'd' THEN 32  END,
    DATEADD(DAY, date_offset, pivotted.begin_date)
  )
    AS end_datetime
FROM
  pivotted
WHERE
  pivotted.schedule_char <> 'h'
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6c52e6718329f2ae013dc93edad5d78